# how to know the class name of the clicked element in jquery?

Tags: jquery, find, classname

I have a doubt about how I get the class name of the clicked element.
Example below.

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="one">ONE</div>
  <div class="two">TWO</div>
  <div class="three">THREE</div>
</div>
```

If I click on any `<div>` inside `"#container"`, I want the class name of the `<div>` in an alert.

Answer (score 0):

You need the following code to get the class name of the clicked item and show in an alert. Place the code at the end of your page.

```
<script>

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("div#container div").click(function() {
            var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
            alert(myClass);
        });
    });

</script>
```

**Edit:**

You need `JQuery` if the above code is not working for you.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```